# How install CA certificate for a wireless network?

Tags: networking, wireless

I need to configure wireless network. To do it I need to install CA certificate. How to do it in ubuntu?

Comment: these setting worked for Ubuntu 12.04 as well.Thanks a tonn

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem ubuntu 13.04. I selected Protected EAP (PEAP) for authentication mode, and ignored choosing a certificate file.

Now I am connected successfully with the following settings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me! Wonder what this actually changes tho..

Comment: @ocean800 This drops the server authentication. Basically, you can no longer be sure you are actually connected to an access point of the network you wanted to connect to. You may want to read up on [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://www.google.com/search?q=mitm).

Comment: @valid So, what is the best (most secure+easy to configure) setting?

Comment: @antmw1361 "Secure" and "easy" are conflicting interests. I'd advise to use certificates and encourage access point owners to have an easy-to-use, properly certified network. Wireless hotspots without cert can be exploited by .. future security experts - the kind that notice your picture's background saying "for? Browse other questions tagged networking wireless" ;). Then again, I also, at times, had priorities that required me to ignore outdated or otherwise improper certificates. It's a good start to feel at least irritated in those cases.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 20.04 for WeWork offices. The connect button is grayed out unless I check the "CA Certificate not required". And of course it can't connect without the CA certificate required by WeWork. Frustratingly WeWork WiFi doesn't support linux. they only have instructions for proprietary operating systems. Not a very developer-friendly workspace.

Comment: That's just nuts: it worked fine for me in my Linux Mint 20.1 at WeWork - even though they make sure in the instructions that you MUST configure a CA Cert, and even explain how to download one.

Answer (score 2):

Some wireless networks use a Certificate Authority file which can be configured in the following place:

Network menu (the four spreading arcs icon) > Edit Connections... > choose your network > Network Security tab > pick "WPA & WPA2 Enterprise" from the pop-down menu > CA Certificate.

(My own use for a CA file is a VPN that requires me to install a CA in my browser. That doesn't seem to be your case.)

Answer (score 2):

I used the `AddTrust_External_Root` found in the mozilla certificates - `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.ca`

Wifi worked.