# AddTrust_External_Root.crt not in /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla. where can I find/install it?

Tags: wireless

I'm trying to follow [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102326/how-install-ca-certificate-for-a-wireless-network/781026#781026) to connect to the XFINITY network but the certificate that they say to use is not in the folder they say it is.

I have searched multiple online sources and all are convinced that it is in that folder when it is not.

[image: not in mozilla folder]

[image: not anywhere]

Do you know where I can find this certificate, or how to connect to the XFINITY network without it?

Comment: That certificate expired a few years ago, so even if you did find it, it wouldn't work. But why would you want to install an arbitrary CA certificate in the first place? Your issue appears to be that you can't connect to a network. See [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I said exactly the underlying problem and why I was trying to solve it, even linked to the guide I was following and the step I was having a problem with. If there is a solution that lets me connect to XFINITY I am fine with that. I said that.

Comment: It will help to edit the title of your question so that it matches what you are asking.