# Which CA Certificate to use when installing Ubuntu 22.04 from a USB?

Tags: networking, 22.04, live-usb, authentication, certificates

I made a bootable USB drive today on Windows, and I am in the process of installing Ubuntu 22.04 on a Windows desktop. One of the first steps in the Ubuntu installation setup is to connect the computer to a wireless network. However, when I do so, I cannot connect until I check the "No CA certificate is required" (which according to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102326/how-install-ca-certificate-for-a-wireless-network#:%7E:text=Network%20menu%20%28the%20four%20spreading%20arcs%20icon%29%20%3E,Enterprise%22%20from%20the%20pop-down%20menu%20%3E%20CA%20Certificate.) allows for man-in-the-middle attacks on my network).

After reading [this](https://superuser.com/questions/117813/authentication-required-by-wireless-network) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102326/how-install-ca-certificate-for-a-wireless-network#:%7E:text=Network%20menu%20%28the%20four%20spreading%20arcs%20icon%29%20%3E,Enterprise%22%20from%20the%20pop-down%20menu%20%3E%20CA%20Certificate.) I looked in the folders `/etc/ssl/certs` and `/usr/share/ca-certificates` to find CA Certificates. The first folder continues a long list of CA certificates, but I don't know which one to use. The latter contains many as well, but the one suggested in the second question (`/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.ca`) is not there.

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: Unless you have configured your WiFi network to use WPA Enterprise authentication, there is no CA certificate to be used.

Comment: You can choose not to connect to Wi-Fi and not download updates during installation. Once Ubuntu is installed connect to Wi-Fi or Ethernet to update the system.

Comment: A man in the middle attack during the ten minutes that a Ubuntu installation (on empty drive, with default settings) needs? Well, possibly in a very congested environment, but at home, with a firewalled AP; naahhh... Run that installation and get updates after first boot.